# Angular- How to open a modal component from outside of a button click

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using ng bootstrap, I have a component called Modal Component in which i will pass modal content dynamically. Below is code which i have written :

this is template file:

```
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
<hr>
```

Below is component file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modaltest',
  templateUrl: './modaltest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modaltest.component.css']
})
export class ModaltestComponent implements OnInit {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {

      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {


      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am unable to open this modal on button click, in which button is defined in another component whose template file is as below :

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)" >Launchss demo modal</button>

<app-modaltest  ></app-modaltest>
```

but onclick of this button it throws error "**TypeError: _co.open is not a function**"

Comment: you need to pass a event to the model component make use of output emitter emit a event which is caught by the parent and then open the modal there . this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) might help . i guess this question is also realated to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536807/how-to-pass-let-c-close-of-modal-template-to-other-components-html-angular-5 . its yours only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just call a method in another component.

What's the relationship of the components in which the button is and the other one with the open() method?

You should probably use `EventEmitter` to emit the button click from the first component and subscribe to in in the other, either by some kind of shared service or Input - Output relationship in the case components have child - parent relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can if you assign a reference.

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="myRef.myMethod()" >Launchss demo modal</button>
<app-modaltest #myRef ></app-modaltest>
```

But not from within the component code, unless you pass that reference to a method

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="localMethod(myRef)" >Launchss demo modal</button>
<app-modaltest #myRef ></app-modaltest>
```